# SwiftUI Mac App with CoreData using secondary WindowGroup

Tags: swift, swiftui, core-data

In a SwiftUI Mac App with CoreData I want to use a second WindowGroup, to present CoreData NSManagedObjects from a List in the primary WindowGroup.

The **for** parameter of the second WindowGroup("Detail Window", for: ????) shall be a Codable & Hashable Type.
I need to transfer a CoreData Managed Object Item.

```
@main
struct MyApp: App {
  let persistenceController = PersistenceController.shared

  var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup {
      ListView()
      .environment(\.managedObjectContext, persistenceController.container.viewContext)
    }
    
    WindowGroup("Detail Window", for: Item.self) { $item in  // does not compile
      CreateEditView(item: item!, mode: .edit)
      .environment(\.managedObjectContext, persistenceController.container.viewContext)
    }
      
    Window("Single Window", id: "sw") {
      SingleWindowView()
    }      
  }
}
```

does not compile, because Item does not conform to the required protocols. What type can I use?
Can I work with an ID instead, as advised in the WWDC 2022 Video "Bringing multiple Windows to your SwiftUI App".
What can I use as ID for an CoreData ManagedObject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily conform your NSManagedObject to `Identifiable` and use the `objectID` property as the unique id since it is always unique.

One problem is that the id type doesn't conform to `Codable` but that can be resolved by converting it to an `URL`.

```
extension Item: Identifiable {
    public var id: URL {
        self.objectID.uriRepresentation()
    }
}
```

And the window group is then declared as

```
WindowGroup(for: Item.ID.self) { $id in
```

Comment: In the view, I have to perform a fetchrequest, right? Isn't that inperformant, because I had the NSObject already requested in the List. Its that the best way?

Comment: How can I fetch the NSObject with this "internal" URL? I think id is not part of the Datamodel.

Comment: Fetching works like this: static func getItem(with uri: URL?) -> Item? {
    let moc = PersistenceController.shared.container.viewContext
    let objectID = moc.persistentStoreCoordinator!.managedObjectID(forURIRepresentation: uri!)
    let item = moc.object(with: objectID! ) as! Item
    return item.  // without any error handling !!!!

Comment: Why not do it inside the view instead perhaps in `onAppear`? But I don't understand what the issue is with getting the object from the context using the id, you asked for a solution using an id instead of the object?

Comment: thanks, is it possible with the NSmanagedObject directly too? The ID Variant was just an alternative, whitch works fine, as you explained.  Which solution would you prefer as “best practice”?

Comment: Apple recommends passing ID values rather than whole objects and this is what I try to follow although if I have a really small type I might use it directly. NSManagedObject doesn't conform to Codable out of the box so it will not work directly and conforming to Codable just because of this use case isn't worth it.